# Facebook Multiple invites using Requests 2.0

Tags: facebook, fbml, apprequests

Is it possible to send multiple invites using new Requests 2.0? Documentation as of now saing that 'to' parameter can specify only one user, so it single user or standart request dialog even without possibility to set default filter! It's huge drawback from hidious by nature, but effective in purpose FBML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

Look in the docs [for Requests 2.0](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/):

> Send to Many
>
> From your application front-end,
>   execute:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.', data: 'tracking data: 'tracking information for the user'});
```

This will open the facebook Dialog: [image]

If you meant in your question whether or not you can filter multiple id's - meaning, you choose the list of uid's to send the request to and not the user - then the answer is no, it's not possible currently.

Comment: Yes, that what i meant. Thank you. Without filter and ability to send requests immediately to predefined uids this invites system can't compare to FBML one. App's using it can't compete with the ones using FBML, so i will have to use it, until better options will arrive.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

```
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests', 
            message: 'text for the receiving user',
            data: '127', // to know what to do with it.
            title: 'title of window.'

        });
```

see this fanpage for an example:
http://www.facebook.com/NeonFashion?sk=app_176086155780033

or i missunderstand your questions and you actual looking for something like
[Facebook requests 2.0 filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329776/facebook-requests-2-0-filter)

Comment: Thank you, i will try this immediately, thou there is no mention of filter property in [the official doc on the matter](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

Comment: you can fill books with what facebook hasnt documented :)

Answer (score 0):

It is (now?) possible to open a request dialog targeting multiple users at once, by passing an array of ids in the "to" field.

See the "sendRequestToManyRecipients" example in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/